# Access variable from another script source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
<script src="http://domain.com/source1.js"></script>
<script src="http://domain.com/source2.js"></script>
```

source1.js

```
var PICTURE_PATH = "";
var PICTURE_ROOT = base_url+"YOUTAILOR_files/";
var PROGRAM = parseInt("1");
```

source2.js

```
 if(PROGRAM==3 || PROGRAM==4 || PROGRAM==5)
 {
 }
```

I could not access value of program in source2.js..

Comment: ...we'll let you know when you kindly show us your code first ;-) there is no way to give you an answer under current circumstances. How should anyone know where your variable sits?

Comment: I've made changes in my question.. @t3chb0t

Comment: Is there anything around "var PROGRAM", like a function ?

Comment: no.. ther is nothing like that @Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare var source1Var outside a function you are actually creating a variable on the window object. So you should just be able to access it from source2.js. Just make sure source1.js is before source2.js in the script tags...

If however you're declaring it within a function, it will be private to that function. If you really need to you could set it on window explicitly.

In source1.js

```
function foo() {
   window.source1Var = 3;
}
```

In source2.js

```
function bar() {
   console.log(source1Var); // this will search window if it cannot find in the local scope.
}
```

What is the problem you're trying to solve? It is generally better to use some form of dependency injection, event listeners, builder pattern etc. rather than using global variables.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.. I've made changes in my question.. See if you can find issue in my code... @Adam

Comment: Forgot to accept it as answer.. :) @Adam.. I did put source1.js before source2.js

Answer (score 0):

do something like in your first .js

```
var VAR = {
    myvalue: "hai"
 };
```

then call it in second  like

```
alert(VAR.myvalue);
```

Comment: OK please put your Source1.js,Source2.js  code here , i mean only the declaration and accesing part

Comment: I've made changes.. @arun

Comment: Ok i think you want variable  Program in your second .js , then change the declaration from var Program=ParceInt("1"); to var Program={ something:"1"}; then call like alert(Program.something);

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think. If variable is global, you should access it from anywhere.

```
// source1.js
var colorCodes = {

  back  : "#fff",
  front : "#888",
  side  : "#369"

};
```

And in another file:

```
// source2.js
alert (colorCodes.back); // alerts `#fff`
```